# Port number showing in Nodejs express folder listing

Tags: node.js, express, port

I have a node js express application which is running on port 3000. when i ran it first it worked. Then when i ran it for the second time, it says the "`port is already in use`". I have checked all the running ports and also searched by specific 3000 port, but still cannot find a process running on 3000 port.

Then i changed the port to 3002 and checked, now the program ran. And when i closed and ran it again, it says "`port is already in use`".

Same is the case when i tried with port 3003.

i tried the below to check for the running ports

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
netstat -an | grep 3000
lsof -i:3000
kill <PID>
```

Afterwards i noticed that when i did a folder listing it showed the folder "3000", "3002", "3003" as folder/file. I don't know what this is.

[image]

below is my www file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('mqtt-node:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3001');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Could anyone help me with why the ran port numbers are showing in the folder listing and also i cannot find any running node ports, but still says the port is already in use.

Comment: Can you share the code in the file that runs `app.listen`?
Edit: Can you also share what's inside the three folders?

Comment: @DaishoArch I have updated the question. And about the folders - even if i see it when running the ls command, there is no folder as such. this is were i am confused on to why the ports are showing in the ls listing. Thank you

Comment: app.set should be used as **app.set(name, value)**. Check the [API reference](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a change in my env file and the issue is resolved. I had defined the port in my .env as `PORT="3000"` and i changed to `PORT=3000`, and it works.

I am not sure why `PORT="3000"` was working in my PC and not in my server. This is why i was not focusing on this factor.